# join two rows with different values in a single row

Tags: mysql, sql

Get two records in a single row

Attempted clause group by without obtaining the desired result.

I have three tables: `direccion`, `punto_suministro`, `r_servicio_punto_suministro`.

```
id_direccion         others_fields
     10                   XXX        
     10                   YYY  


id_punto_suministro            id_r_servicio_punto_suministro 
       6                            1   
       7                            2   


id_r_servicio_punto_suministro     id_servicio_gas    id_servicio_luz
 1                                   6                 null   
 2                                  null                7
```

query:

```
SELECT 
    punto_suministro.id_direccion,
CASE WHEN  r_servicio_punto_suministro.id_servicio_gas IS NOT NULL THEN punto_suministro.id_punto_suministro END AS Gas,
CASE WHEN  r_servicio_punto_suministro.id_servicio_luz IS NOT NULL THEN punto_suministro.id_punto_suministro END AS Luz
FROM 
    direccion 
    LEFT JOIN punto_suministro ON direccion.id_direccion = punto_suministro.id_direccion 
    LEFT JOIN r_servicio_punto_suministro ON punto_suministro.id_r_servicio_punto_suministro = r_servicio_punto_suministro.id_r_servicio_punto_suministro  
    LEFT JOIN servicio_gas ON r_servicio_punto_suministro.id_servicio_gas = servicio_gas.id_servicio_gas 
    LEFT JOIN servicio_luz ON r_servicio_punto_suministro.id_servicio_luz = servicio_luz.id_servicio_luz
WHERE direccion.id_direccion = 10;
```

The Query returned two rows:

```
 id_direccion     Gas      Luz
     10           6        null
     10           null     7
```

I would like the result in a single record:

```
 id_direccion     Gas      Luz
     10           6        7
```

Comment: Use `GROUP BY` and `max()` for aggregation

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation. You just need to modify your query to surround the `CASE`s with an aggregate function such as `MAX()` (`MIN()` would equally do the job), and add a `GROUP BY` clause at the end:

```
SELECT 
    punto_suministro.id_direccion,
    MAX(CASE WHEN  r_servicio_punto_suministro.id_servicio_gas IS NOT NULL THEN punto_suministro.id_punto_suministro END) AS Gas,
    MAX(CASE WHEN  r_servicio_punto_suministro.id_servicio_luz IS NOT NULL THEN punto_suministro.id_punto_suministro END) AS Luz
FROM 
    direccion 
    LEFT JOIN punto_suministro ON direccion.id_direccion = punto_suministro.id_direccion 
    LEFT JOIN r_servicio_punto_suministro ON punto_suministro.id_r_servicio_punto_suministro = r_servicio_punto_suministro.id_r_servicio_punto_suministro  
    LEFT JOIN servicio_gas ON r_servicio_punto_suministro.id_servicio_gas = servicio_gas.id_servicio_gas 
    LEFT JOIN servicio_luz ON r_servicio_punto_suministro.id_servicio_luz = servicio_luz.id_servicio_luz
WHERE direccion.id_direccion = 10
GROUP BY punto_suministro.id_direccion;
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, with a `LEFT JOIN` and aggregation, you want to aggregate by values from the first table.

Because you are using `LEFT JOIN`, I am guessing that you want a row returned even when there is no match on the `WHERE` clause.

To ensure one row, use an aggregation query *with no `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT MAX(d.id_direccion) as id_direccion,
       MAX(CASE WHEN sps.id_servicio_gas IS NOT NULL THEN ps.id_punto_suministro END) AS Gas,
       MAX(CASE WHEN sps.id_servicio_luz IS NOT NULL THEN ps.id_punto_suministro END) AS Luz
FROM direccion d LEFT JOIN
     punto_suministro ps
     ON d.id_direccion = ps.id_direccion LEFT JOIN
     r_servicio_punto_suministro sps
     ON ps.id_r_servicio_punto_suministro = sps.id_r_servicio_punto_suministro LEFT JOIN 
     servicio_gas sg
     ON sps.id_servicio_gas = sg.id_servicio_gas LEFT JOIN
     servicio_luz sl
     ON spm.id_servicio_luz = sl.id_servicio_luz
WHERE d.id_direccion = 10;
```

If you know that `10` exists in the data, then you can use `GROUP BY d.id_direccion`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers.
I finally fixed it with the joins:

```
SELECT 
direccion.id_direccion,
cups_gas.id_punto_suministro AS Gas,
cups_luz.id_punto_suministro AS Luz
FROM
direccion
    INNER JOIN
(SELECT 
    cups,
        id_direccion,
        punto_suministro.id_punto_suministro,
        atr,
        ca,
        fecha_fin
FROM
    punto_suministro
INNER JOIN r_servicio_punto_suministro ON r_servicio_punto_suministro.id_r_servicio_punto_suministro = punto_suministro.id_r_servicio_punto_suministro
INNER JOIN servicio_gas ON r_servicio_punto_suministro.id_servicio_gas = servicio_gas.id_servicio_gas
INNER JOIN r_contrato_punto_suministro ON punto_suministro.id_punto_suministro = r_contrato_punto_suministro.id_punto_suministro
INNER JOIN contrato ON r_contrato_punto_suministro.id_contrato = contrato.id_contrato
INNER JOIN r_servicio_contrato ON contrato.id_contrato = r_servicio_contrato.id_contrato
INNER JOIN servicio ON r_servicio_contrato.id_servicio = servicio.id_servicio) cups_gas ON direccion.id_direccion = cups_gas.id_direccion
    INNER JOIN
(SELECT 
    cups,
        id_direccion,
        punto_suministro.id_punto_suministro,
        atr,
        ca,
        fecha_fin
FROM
    punto_suministro
INNER JOIN r_servicio_punto_suministro ON r_servicio_punto_suministro.id_r_servicio_punto_suministro = punto_suministro.id_r_servicio_punto_suministro
INNER JOIN servicio_luz ON r_servicio_punto_suministro.id_servicio_luz = servicio_luz.id_servicio_luz
INNER JOIN r_contrato_punto_suministro ON punto_suministro.id_punto_suministro = r_contrato_punto_suministro.id_punto_suministro
INNER JOIN contrato ON r_contrato_punto_suministro.id_contrato = contrato.id_contrato
INNER JOIN r_servicio_contrato ON contrato.id_contrato = r_servicio_contrato.id_contrato
INNER JOIN servicio ON r_servicio_contrato.id_servicio = servicio.id_servicio) cups_luz ON direccion.id_direccion = cups_luz.id_direccion
WHERE
direccion.id_direccion = 10;
```

best regard.